# How to send multiple json objects to a django model serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

This is my modelserializer

```
class Testmasterserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Dime3d_testmaster
       fields = ('visitId','testId','testType','status')
```

I want to send multiple json object how can I send

```
[{
    "visitId": "wsTp6anrDBQE",
    "testId": "RVeaJn6n",
    "testType": "windlass",
    "status": "fine"
},
{
    "visitId": "wsTp6anrDBQE",
    "testId": "Sq3LxKsNDP",
    "testType": "windlass",
    "status": "fine"
}
]
```

Like this. How can I do it. Is there anyway? I dont want to use nested serializer as in that one params is added as like this

```
["data" :{
    "visitId": "wsTp6anrDBQE",
    "testId": "RVeaJn6n",
    "testType": "windlass",
    "status": "fine"
},
{
    "visitId": "wsTp6anrDBQE",
    "testId": "Sq3LxKsNDP",
    "testType": "windlass",
    "status": "fine"
}
]
```

I dont want this

Comment: Instead of trying to handle it on the backend, which would go against common RESTful and DRF design patterns and require quite a bit of coding work to ensure it runs correctly. Since it is non-obvious, it will be also hard to maintain in the future. Try sending the objects seperately with multiple POST requests from your client.

Comment: tysm I found the solution finally!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution just put

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=isinstance(request.data,list))
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

in views.py under your serializerview